# python:numpy array slicing of 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I initialise an array as a=numpy.array([1,2,3]).
on running the statement print(a[0,:]), it shows an error. Does this slicing method only work for 2d arrays?

Comment: you have 2 indexes in there, you only need one,

Comment: Why is there a comma in your index?  Do you understand what it does?

Comment: the print statement above should print the entire(first) row...this statement works fine in 2d array and prints the 1st row, but in 1d array it gives error, can someone explain

Comment: @AdnanZahid as mentioned in my answer your array is of shape (3.), for addressing the array in the manner you mentioned you need the vector to be at least 2-dimensional. Therefore, in your case it is simplest to just make your array 2-dimensional, by adding a new axis with a length of one. Question now is: should `a` be a column vector, in which case the first row would only consist of the number `1`. Then instead of my answer, you would need `a = a[:, np.newaxis]`, or `a` is a row vector, then the first row is the complete array `[1, 2, 3]` in which case my given answer is the one you need

Comment: AFAIK using `a[0:]` simply accesses all elements of `a` starting from the 0th element, therefore it doesn't make any sense, as it is completely the same as just using `a` without any indexing. For example, if you use `print(a[1:])`, you should get `[2, 3]` as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace "a[0,:]" with "a[0:]".

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(a[0:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this issue with

```
a = a[np.newaxis, :]
```

before printing, making it to a `1 x 3` array instead of having shape (3,). Obviously this only makes sense, if you need your printing statement for other multidimensional arrays also and want to make it work in a generalized way.